# Attempting to install gearmand on AWS Linux EC2, yum can't find necessary packages with default repos

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, yum, gearman

I'm attempting to install gearmand on a micro EC2 instance running Amazon Linux 64 bit by following this guide: http://planet.mysql.com/entry/?id=28654

But I'm running into a problem with

```
sudo yum install -y libevent-devel.i386
```

I get the following output:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities, security, update-motd
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * amzn-main: packages.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
 * amzn-updates: packages.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
amzn-main                                                               | 2.1 kB     00:00     
amzn-updates                                                            | 2.1 kB     00:00     
Setting up Install Process
No package libevent-devel.i386 available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Is there a repository I should add to yum to install these packages? And if so, how do I add a repository to yum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

shouldn't it be `libevent-devel.x86_64`?

and you can install with

```
sudo yum install -y libevent-devel
```

Comment: Thanks @cxase, I had put off this little project but your suggestion worked. :)